# JR Server: How to allow user to input time parameters for grouping data in report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to *JasperReports Server*.

I have a report which is grouped on time interval.

I want to user give the input to group the data in minutes, hours or days. Based on the user input, report must group the records accordingly.

I am not able to figure out the way.
Please help.

Comment: you can send the parameter from you code.

Comment: @Prashant Are you looking solution for *JR Server*?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I have developed a report using ireport and running using JR server

Answer (score 0):

Create a input control "p_days" and add  this line in select statement of your query

```
 SELECT days,hours,minutes,
 if($P{p_days} is null, days, hours) p_groupby
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY p_groupby
 ORDER BY p_groupby
```

but this will work for only days and hours.